# Attempt to read property "Is_Admin" on null

Tags: php, laravel

in the database i have is_admin + is_ac columns which's specify if the user is admin or not , and if s/he have an account or not , im not quite sure how to put that up in the sign up code

signup code

```
function signup(Request $req)
{
    // return $rep -> input();
    $user = new User;
    $user->Name = $req->name; 
    $user->Email = $req->email; 
    $user->Password = Hash::make($req->password); 
    $user->save();
}
```

login code just in case

```
function login(Request $req)
{
    $user = User::where(['Username' => $req->username])->first();        
    $IsAdmin = $user->Is_Admin;
    $IsActive = $user->Is_Ac;
    if (!$user || !Hash::check($req->password, $user->Password) || $IsActive == 0) {
        return("Username or Password is not matched or User is InActive");
    } else {
        $req->session()->put('user', $user);
        $req->session()->put('IsAdmin', $IsAdmin);
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: so, your error is very basic... `->first()` returns the model or `null`, in your case, it is `null`, so you cannot do `null->is_admin`...

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs changes:

```php
public function login(Request $req)
{
    $user = User::where(['Username' => $req->username])->first();

    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($req->password, $user->Password) || ! $user->Is_Ac) {
        return("Username or Password is not matched or User is InActive");
    }

    $req->session()->put('user', $user);
    $req->session()->put('IsAdmin', $user->Is_Admin);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

See how I updated your `login` method. I moved the `$user->xxx` into the `if` but after we checked if `$user` has content, then you can do `$user->xxx`.

And also see that I have removed the `else`. You need to read about `If Guard Clauses` [here](https://engineering.helpscout.com/reducing-complexity-with-guard-clauses-in-php-and-javascript-74600fd865c7) and [here](https://codenphp.blogspot.com/search?q=replace%20nested%20conditions%20with%20guard%20clauses%20).

Comment: but the error comes from the signup code , the login works perfectly fine

Comment: @user498543769 you are not setting any of the one showing errors... share the full error and model code please...

Answer (score 0):

When you try to fetch the user, you will get a nullable user result (either null or a user).

```
$user=User::where (['Username'=>$req->username])->first();
```

Now the first thing you should do is to check if the user is existing or not, and only after trying to read isAdmin and isActive.

```
function login(Request $req){
    $user=User::where(['Username' => $req->username])->first();        

    if(!$user || !Hash::check($req->password, $user->Password)
           || $user->Is_Ac ==0) {
        return "Username or Password is not matched or User is InActive";
    }

    $req->session()->put('user', $user);
    $req->session()->put('IsAdmin', $user->Is_Admin);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: I just noticed I wrote almost the same that @matiaslauriti wrote